# Where does the recurring tale of a spiritual / paranormal sake banquet in the woods coming from?

Tags: culture, xxxholic, mushishi

I watched both *xxxHolic* and *Mushishi*, and in both anime there is a recurring tale, where a banquet is held in the woods, where either people or spirits (or mushis in *Mushishi*) are obtaining some delicious golden sake.

I was trying to find out if that was a coincidence that it was happening in both shows, thinking it might come from some japanese folklore. But I couldn't find anything.

Comment: doesn't fully answer your question, but the answer to this [more general question on where the mushishi stories come from](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/696/which-mythologies-or-folktales-inspired-the-stories-in-mushishi), it's possible it's a coincidence between the two though